# Jmeter - Json Extractor removing white space causes test to fail

Tags: json, jmeter

Apologees if this is something fundamental which I should already know.
I've got a test set up in jmeter using a Json Extractor.
The data which it is extracting is in the format:

```
"data item 1", "data item 2", "data item 3"
```

The problem I have is that the extractor is pulling the data out and removing the spaces.

Is this normal? Or is there a setting I need to tweak to stop it doing this?

The service under test is using a Swagger page as a front end and the output from the service is in the format I describe above.

I can alter my expected results to remove all the spaces, but this may cause issues further down the line.

Any help much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It should not be removing anything, can you please update your question with partial (or better full) response and JSON Path expression you're using

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post the actual response as the testing is on a separate, secure system and we're not allowed to copy stuff. Not exactly helpful I know! Am going to try dropping the response message through the Poster add-in for Chrome and see if that shows up with spaces or not. It may even be a service related issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming following is the JSON response

```
{
key1: "data item 1",
key2: "data item 2",
key3: "data item 3"
}
```

Now I am extracting Key1 value using

```
1. Regular expression extraction 
2. JSON Extractor
```

Both "Post processor" are never going to strip the spaces between words

```
Examples:       
                 Actual Value: data item 1
Your assumed Extracted Value : dataitem1
       JMeter Extracted Value: data item 1
```

JMeter never going to strip the actual extracted values.Below is the examples.

Jmeter "Http Sampler" has two "Post processor" as child for demo purpose, and sampler uses following json url https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mcheepati/api/master/demo.json .Shown below

[image]

After running the test , following are extracted values (Debug sampler used for this)

[image]

For reference , please download source jmx file execute in your load Jmeter 3.1, [Link](https://github.com/mcheepati/api/blob/master/json_demo.jmx)

Comment: How to do this if the key, and not the value, has blank spaces?